# Small item listing template

Tags: javascript

I want to create something like [this](http://www.antonoffplus.com)

Do I need to create it with JS/jQuery? And how it will be look like? Any code snippets, please..
When for example I choose 1b it will return me 1 image, when 2a it would return other image

1
2
3

a
b
c

UPDATE:

```
  <script>

    //returning frame data att
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $('.frame').click(function(){
            alert($(this).data("frame"));
            });
        });
    }); 


    //returning roof data att
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $('.roof').click(function(){
            alert($(this).data("roof"));
            });
        });
    }); 



    </script>
```

```
    <h3>Frame</h3>
    <a href="#" class="frame" data-frame="1">Blue</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="frame" data-frame="2">Red</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="frame" data-frame="3">Green</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="frame" data-frame="4">Purple</a>


    <h3>Roof</h3>  

    <a href="#" class="roof" data-roof="1">Clear</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="roof" data-roof="2">Moodust</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="roof" data-roof="3">Yellow</a><br/>
```

Now I have alert, which box has been clicked. Now I need to group them out. And for example when I click on box blue it will select blue and when I click on Clear, it would be selected it, and show me the output of image 1_1.jpeg, or something like that

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/antonoff/pPvmy/

Comment: Try to begin to code, and i'll help you to finish. You have the algorythm, so it won't be difficult to do that... Else, your words 'any code snippets please'... are not welcome if you don't show any work from yourself....

Comment: I have updated, how long I have gone for these time, I hope you will understand, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the image url with : http://jsfiddle.net/pPvmy/1/

In this code, imageurl is your url...

```
var framechoice = '';
var roofchoice='';

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function(){
            $('.frame').click(function(){
                alert($(this).data("frame"));
                framechoice = $(this).data("frame");
                });
            });
        }); 

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function(){
            $('.roof').click(function(){
                alert($(this).data("roof"));
                roofchoice = $(this).data("roof");

                if( framechoice !='' && roofchoice != '')
                {
                    var imageurl = 'image'+ framechoice +'_'+roofchoice+'.jpg';
                    alert(imageurl);
                }

                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, I will go to modify it